# Speed cannot be greater than speed of light. How about acceleration? Does it have limit?

Tags: acceleration, relativity

We know that $c$ is the largest speed in the universe. How about the acceleration, does it has limit?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101985/2451

Answer (score 4):

As Sachin says, there is no limit to acceleration. In fact you can show this by considering an observer hovering at a fixed distance from a black hole. As described [in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/what-is-the-weight-equation-through-general-relativity), the acceleration required to maintain a fixed distance from a black hole is given by:

$$ a = \frac{GM}{r^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}} $$

where $r_s$ is the radius of the event horizon. As $r \rightarrow r_s$ the term $\sqrt{1-r_s/r} \rightarrow 0$ and the acceleration goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

There's no theoretical limit to acceleration. On the surface of Black Holes, the acceleration is literally infinite, for example. However, there'll be practical challenges to achieve that.

Comment: High amounts of energy are not required for a high acceleration, since the time scale at which this occurs can be small.

Comment: @fibonatic Prove it mathematically..

Comment: John Rennie's example is clear enough: the acceleration doesn't change the energy since it's perpendicular to the velocity vector. (Assuming a circular orbit).