# Acceleration limit

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, acceleration, speed-of-light

From the theory of relativity, we know that the highest speed achievable for any massive object is the speed of light. So we can say $c$ is the speed limit is there some similar limit on maximum acceleration achievable if yes then how to explain it in principle if not then what if a body accelerates with $3\times10^9 m/s^2$  won't that break the speed limit?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3334 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101985 are the same questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those linked questions are closed, and I do not like to use closed questions as duplicate targets. Also, most of those answers are not purely about relativity, they invoke quantum effects.

Comment: @PM2Ring if we neglect quantum mechanics the answer is trivial and will be $\infty$. For example, in [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) the observer going along the Rindler horizon will have $\infty$ proper acceleration.

Comment: @Kasi Of course, since $v=c\tanh\left(\frac{aT}{c}\right)$